# what is max-age property in HSTS security header?

Tags: http, security, https

what is the purpose of max-age in HSTS ? such as:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=100
```

If the value exceeds 100, what will happen ?

is there any best practice of setting the max-age ?

thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are semantically distinct ways to send HSTS headers, as defined in [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797):

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

The HSTS policy is applied only to the domain of HSTS host issuing it and remains in effect for one year.

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

The HSTS policy is applied to the domain of the issuing host as well as its subdomains and remains in effect for one year.

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
```

Directs the browser to delete the entire HSTS policy.

**HSTS Best Practices**

There are a few simple best practices for HSTS:

1. The strongest protection is to ensure that all requested resources use only TLS with a well-formed HSTS header. Qualys recommends providing an HSTS header on all HTTPS resources in the target domain.
2. It is advisable to assign the max-age directive’s value to be greater than 10368000 seconds (120 days) and ideally to 31536000 (one year). Websites should aim to ramp up the max-age value to ensure heightened security for a long duration for the current domain and/or subdomains.
3. RFC 6797, section 14.4 advocates that a web application must aim to add the `includeSubDomain` directive in the policy definition whenever possible. The directive’s presence ensures the HSTS policy is applied to the domain of the issuing host and all of its subdomains, e.g. `example.com` and `www.example.com`.
4. The application should never send an HSTS header over a plaintext HTTP header, as doing so makes the connection vulnerable to SSL stripping attacks.
5. It is not recommended to provide an HSTS policy via the http-equiv attribute of a meta tag. According to HSTS RFC 6797, user agents don’t heed http-equiv=”Strict-Transport-Security” attribute on  elements on the received content.

This [cheat sheet from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet) might help you out in future too.